# Select n elements in matrix left-wise based on certain value

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a logical matrix A, and I would like to select all the elements to the left of each of my 1s values given a fixed distant. Let's say my distance is 4, I would like to (for instance) replace with a fixed value (saying 2) all the 4 cells at the left of each 1 in A.

```
A= [0 0 0 0 0 1 0
   0 1 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 1 0 1]

B= [0 2 2 2 2 1 0
   2 1 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   2 2 2 2 2 2 1]
```

In B is what I would like to have, considering also overwrting (last row in B), and cases where there is only 1 value at the left of my 1 and not 4 as the fixed searching distance (second row).

Comment: What have you tried? Can you do it for a single vector, and have you considered just looping over the rows?

Comment: Yes, like in the last row of the example. It's not a problem if sometimes some 1 is overwritten by a 2 during this operation (like again the last row of the matrix in my example)

Comment: It should be 0, as I would change only the 4 cells to the left, and that 0 was the fifth.

Comment: Have undone the wrongfull edit and adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this lovely one-liner?

```
n = 3;
const = 5;
A = [0 0 0 0 0 1 0;
     0 1 0 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 1 0 1]

A(bsxfun(@ne,fliplr(filter(ones(1,1+n),1,fliplr(A),[],2)),A)) = const
```

results in:

```
A =

     0     0     5     5     5     1     0
     5     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     5     5     5     5     5     1
```

here some explanations:

```
Am = fliplr(A);                      %// mirrored input required
Bm = filter(ones(1,1+n),1,Am,[],2);  %// moving average filter for 2nd dimension
B = fliplr(Bm);                      %// back mirrored
mask = bsxfun(@ne,B,A)               %// mask for constants
A(mask) = const
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple solution you could have come up with:

```
w=4;                            % Window size
v=2;                            % Desired value

B = A;
for r=1:size(A,1)               % Go over all rows
  for c=2:size(A,2)             % Go over all columns
    if A(r,c)==1                % If we encounter a 1
       B(r,max(1,c-w):c-1)=v;   % Set the four spots before this point to your value (if possible)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
d = 4; %// distance
v = 2; %// value

A = fliplr(A).'; %'// flip matrix, and transpose to work along rows.
ind = logical( cumsum(A) ...
    - [ zeros(size(A,1)-d+2,size(A,2)); cumsum(A(1:end-d-1,:)) ] - A );
A(ind) = v;
A = fliplr(A.');
```

Result:

```
A =
     0     2     2     2     2     1     0
     2     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     2     2     2     2     2     2     1
```

Answer (score 2):

**Approach #1** One-liner using **[`imdilate`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/images/ref/imdilate.html)** available with Image Processing Toolbox -

```
A(imdilate(A,[ones(1,4) zeros(1,4+1)])==1)=2
```

**Explanation**

**Step #1:** Create a morphological structuring element to be used with `imdilate` -

```
morph_strel = [ones(1,4) zeros(1,4+1)]
```

This basically represents a window extending `n` places to the left with ones and n places to the right including the origin with zeros.

**Step #2:** Use `imdilate` that will modify `A` such that we would have `1` at all four places to the left of each `1` in `A` -

```
imdilate_result = imdilate(A,morph_strel)
```

**Step #3:** Select all four indices for each `1` of `A` and set them to `2` -

```
A(imdilate_result==1)=2
```

Thus, one can write a general form for this approach as -

```
A(imdilate(A,[ones(1,window_length) zeros(1,window_length+1)])==1)=new_value
```

where `window_length` would be `4` and `new_value` would be `2` for the given data.

---

**Approach #2** Using **[`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)**-

```
%// Paramters
window_length = 4;
new_value = 2;

B = A' %//'
[r,c] = find(B)
extents = bsxfun(@plus,r,-window_length:-1)
valid_ind1 = extents>0
jump_factor = (c-1)*size(B,1)
extents_valid = extents.*valid_ind1
B(nonzeros(bsxfun(@plus,extents_valid,jump_factor).*valid_ind1))=new_value
B = B' %// B is the desired output
```